# Where does AWS SES stores its custom templates, Can we have cross region replica for these SES templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When a template is creates in SES, where does it gets stored.
Also how can i achieve cross region replica for SES templates, suppose i create template in US-West in Oregon region and would like to get the same template in US-East N.Virginia region.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are region specific and there are currently no options to automatically replicate your templates across regions.

A possible solution is to deploy your templates with CloudFormation using the [AWS::SES::Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-template.html) resource and deploy your stack in multiple regions.